# How to convert a string to date in SAP HANA SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, hana

How do I convert a string `'20120215'` to a date format `YYYY-MM-DD` (`2012-02-15`) in a SQL `SELECT` statement in HANA?

I am using SAP HANA SQL.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time and string handling many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: i am using SAP HANA SQL

Comment: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/ec6b6975191014b835eb436e4827df/content.htm

Comment: i tried this `TO_DATE` function but it was not helpful as my string is in a format like `YYYYMMDD` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20100112', 'YYYYMMDD') "to date" FROM DUMMY;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE('20120215', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') "to date" FROM DUMMY;
```

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) mentioned, you can use the [SAP HANA SQL and System Views Reference](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US) for help on writing queries.